# Multithreading / asynchronously in Php codeigniter

Tags: php, multithreading, codeigniter

In my controller I load the HTML using view.
Now before the view loads, I need to call 2 more functions. So what happens is, it waits for the function 1 to finish (5-6 seconds) and then 2nd function to finish (another 5-6 seconds) and the view loads. is it possible to run both the functions together so that the view can run faster

> ```
> public function index() {  
>
>    $empid = "12345";
>
>    //running function / step / process / one 
>
>    $this->function1($empid);
>
>    //running function / step / process / two
>
>    $this->function2($empid);
>
>    $this->load->view("welcome",$data);
>
> }
> ```

Comment: You can set AJAX call(s) to these methods with some kind of alert when those are done. BAsically you would just load view with JS code of `$(document).ready(function { $.ajax({/*code for those methods with callback of done info*/}) });`.

Comment: I take it the view does not need the results of either function1 or function2?

Comment: @DFriend - no it does not need the result from function1 or function2

Comment: @Tpojka - if there is no other way then yes, i will need to run AJAX on view and then call the 2 function. the problem is, the name of the function will be visible from the client side browser

Comment: What you can do is to disallow non AJAX requests. Chech somewhere at the bottom of Input class library in the docs, if applicable that way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use PHP's `exec()` function. ([Read about `exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [more info here](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/).)
This can be implemented a couple of ways:

1. Create a standalone php file that will be executed.
2. Create a Controller that will be executed.

Option 1 can be very light-weight as you only need to create a php file with the code you want to run. But it won't have access to Codeigniter libraries. If you do need/want to use CI within the "process" then Option 2 is what you want.

I will show how to implement option 2. This utilizes Codeigniter's ability to be run from the command line (CLI). ([Read about that here.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html)) We will emulate that functionality by using `exec()`.

This is setup to prove the functions get called and work. They basically run some time-consuming tasks a lot of times so we can actually see that the browser is blocked while they execute.

Create a controller with methods to be called through `exec()` and put it in `application/controllers`.

**Tools.php**

```
class Tools extends CI_Controller
{
    public function proc1($param = 1)
    {
        $time_start = microtime(true);
        for($i = 1; $i < $param ; $i++)
        {
            sqrt($i);
        }
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;
        $iters = number_format($param);
        echo "Proc1 calculated $iters square roots in $time seconds\n";
    }

    public function proc2($param = 1)
    {
        $time_start = microtime(true);
        for($i = 1; $i < $param; $i++)
        {
            log10 ($i);
        }
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;
        $iters = number_format($param);
        echo "Proc2 calculated $iters Base-10 logarithms in $time seconds\n";
    }

}
```

Here is the controller that will make the calls to `exec()`.

```
class Proc_test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Index is running<br>";
        $param = 5000000;
        $command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools proc1 $param";
        $out = [];
        exec($command, $out);
        var_dump($out);

        $command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools proc2 $param";
        $out = [];
        exec($command, $out);
        var_dump($out);

        echo "Procs have been called";
    }
}
```

Make the call to the new controller e.g. `http://example.com/proc_test

With `$param` set to 5-million it takes my system a bit over 8 seconds to show the result. Try it a few times changing the value of `$param` to see different results.

Obviously, we don't want the browser to block. That is fixed by simple changes in `Proc_test.php`

Change the two lines where `$command` is assigned values to these.

```
$command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools proc1 $param > /dev/null &";
```

and

```
$command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools proc2 $param > /dev/null &";
```

The `> /dev/null &` essentially tells php to send the return to a blackhole. That means nobody has to wait for the process to finish.

Refresh the page. Yeah! No blocking!

Since we don't care that these procs return anything the lines of code in my example can be removed. So `proc1()` could look like this

```
public function proc1($param = 1)
{
    for($i = 1; $i < $param; $i++)
    {
        sqrt($i);
    }
}
```

So. For your particular case: In the `index()` method of your question replace these lines

```
$this->function1($empid);
$this->function2($empid);
```

with these

```
$command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools function1 $empid > /dev/null &";
exec($command);

$command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools function1 $empid > /dev/null &";
exec($command);
```

Obviously the functions names have to be changed in `Tools.php` to match what you provide to `$command`.

This is long enough, but if you want to see how to implement this without involving codeigniter let me know.